# Parent div responsiveness with inner div

Tags: html, css

I need to have div border responsive. However, as you can see `.buttonsDiv` needs to be at the bottom and wrapper border needs to be stretched underneath `.buttonsDiv`. But when I use this code buttons are at the bottom but border stays at the top. I can't use margin because content div contains elements that are shown/hidden and the page needs to be fixed `aka` disabled scrolling.

**html**

```css
.wrapper { 
   border: 1px solid black; 
}

.buttonsDiv {
   position: fixed;
   bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="wrapper">
   <div class="borderedDiv">Content</div>
   <div class="buttonsDiv">Butons</div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to position fixed or do you ned it to be absolute ? Position fixed will always stay fixed in the viewport after the scroll.

Comment: are you looking like this? https://jsfiddle.net/4bp3jork/5/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put **position: absolute;** to the parent and define top, bottom, left, right as 0;

*PS: This solution will not add scroll bar which appears if you put height 100vh*

```css
.wrapper { 
   border: 1px solid black; 
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
   top: 0;
   right: 0;
   left: 0
}

.buttonsDiv {
   position: fixed;
   bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="borderedDiv">Content</div>
   <div class="buttonsDiv">Butons</div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Yes you are right this solution is superior, nice answer. I learned something ;)

Comment: Happy to see the above comment :)

Comment: Didn't think to use position: absolute on the wrapper. Nice job

Answer (score 4):

Its hard to understand what you are after. Do you mean something like this?

```css
 html, body{
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
 }
 
 .wrapper{ 
   height: 100vh;
   width: 100vw;
   padding: 10px;
   box-sizing: border-box;
 }
 
 .inner_wrap{
   position:relative;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   border: 1px solid black;
   box-sizing: border-box;
 }
 
 .buttonsDiv{
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 10px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="inner_wrap">
    <div class="borderedDiv">Content</div>
    <div class="buttonsDiv">Butons</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice solution. But it adds a vertical scroll bar :(

Comment: @ivp fixed the scroll bar

Answer (score 2):

To add to the previous answer:

```css
    .wrapper { 
       border: 1px solid black; 
       height: 100vh;
    }
    
    .buttonsDiv {
       position: absolute;
       bottom: 1px;
    }
```

```html
 <div class="wrapper">
   <div class="borderedDiv">Content</div>
   <div class="buttonsDiv">Butons</div>
 </div>
```

The wrapper doesn't need an position: relative, position static will do fine.
With the position absolute of the button div you place the element relative to its **parent element**. Therefore if we put `.buttonsDiv` to bottom:1px it will stick to the bottom of the element.

Comment: Nice solution. But it adds a vertical scroll bar :(